# The app which has published in Google store can not be lanchered by the voice of Google Assistant

Tags: publish

The related app I have published in Google Store ,I kown App Action testing must be completed on a physical Android device. but when Attempting to invoke App Actions on a virtual device using Assistant can result in the response "Sorry, I couldn't find that" instead of the expected deep link.I would like to know what I should do to fix this issue ,thanks very much!The develope account is :empg.ev